# xcode conditions on view

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface-builder

I have a complicated controller with a XIB interface view. I would like to change 2 labels' positions(a slight shift) on some condition. I don't want to hardcode new coordinates of labels in my code, because it's not a flexible solution (in the future somebody can change labels' positions in XIB and hardcoded positions will be incorrect).

So, what can I do for this problem?  Should I duplicate XIB and pick one of them on some condition? Or may be is there a more elegant solution?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should shift them relative to the their current position

```
CGRect LabelFrame = Mylabel.frame ;
LabelFrame.origin.x +=something ;
Mylabel.frame = LabelFrame;
```

This will make it shift in the x direction by something.

You can do this in a UIView animation block to animate shift

Comment: yes, it's not bad. May be it will be better to use coordinates of neighbor UI elements. Thanks